# Why do people still use Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-7

I'm sure like most developers, you have gotten your code perfect only to test it on IE7 and it doesn't look right.

My analytics say that IE7 is one of the lower ranking versions of IE being used to view my website. My question is why do people still use IE7? Isn't it easier to update to a better version of IE than to still be on 7?

I'm not sure why you would be on such an old version of IE unless you are not computer literate and only use it for basic tasks.

I tried researching on the web but no such luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people simply don't have a choice if their IT department has not upgraded them. If you're building your application for a specific client, build it to the lowest version they have to support.  If you're just doing this on your own to publish, then just support 'modern' browser versions.

Comment: I see. Would it really take a ton of effort to upgrade lets say 100 computers to a new version of IE?? I know it might take time but from my perspective it seems simple...

Comment: To upgrade IE?  No, probably not, not as long as they have decent upgrade processes.  But it takes a LONG time to verify that all of their corporate applictions, especially things like SAP, have been made aware of the newer version of the browser.    So they could easily upgrade to IE <whatever> but then suddenly their critical business app fails because it expects things to work like they did in IE 7, not IE 11.

Comment: The other thing you'll see is that the box has IE 10, but it's running in compatibility mode, so it says "Hey, even though I'm 10, I'm going to act like 7".  A fortune 100 company I work for just last year finally shut off compatibility mode.

Comment: Ok thats make a little more sense. I guess if you are thinking of it from a company wide view, the apps might not behave the same version to version. I've noticed the compatibility mode as well. Man I just hate developing for IE7, its like a separate project.

Comment: Please mark my reply as the answer if your question was answered.